# div Hover Issue when reaches border

Tags: html, css

I want hover effect on div, I have applied bottom style when hover on div and everything is working but when hover border/edge of the div means the div jerking/jumping continuously.

my code :

```css
.traning-box {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.traning-box:hover {
  bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="traning-box">
  <p> Test box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added sample on jsfiddle :
 http://jsfiddle.net/de3Qv/6/

Comment: You could use script to achieve this hover effect.

Comment: jquery script will be solution for this

Comment: @Nageswar which type of effect you want

Comment: Move up 15px when the hover

Comment: on hover what it has to do?

Comment: Move up and Move down 15px

Comment: well, what you get is logic, you hover on an element its moves so the mouse leave, the element bet back to its positon, the mouse hover again, it moves again, etc, etc ... so it's not an issue, but something logic

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:after` pseudo-element. When the `.traning-box` goes up, the `:after` goes down, so the cursor will still over the `.traning-box` (because it is a parent block for the `:after`).

```css
.traning-box {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
}

.traning-box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.traning-box:hover {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.traning-box:hover:after {
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="traning-box">
  <p>Test box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: don't know why this get downvoted, but it seems the only one without jumping effect

Answer (score 0):

You could use `animation` to achieve it.

```css
.traning-box {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
}

.traning-box:hover {
  animation-name:move;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}

@keyframes move{
  50%{
    transform:translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="traning-box">
  <p> Test box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is still jumping effect here when you are in the border bottom

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `transition` and `translate` together to achieve smooth hover effect.

```css
.traning-box {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.traning-box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="traning-box">
  <p> Test box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you still have the jumping effect here too when you are in the bottom border

Answer (score -2):

Try below. You have to use inner div to write a hover effect.

```css
.traning-box{
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
.traning-box1 {width:120px;}

.traning-box1:hover .traning-box{
  bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="traning-box1">
<div class="traning-box">
                <p> Test box</p>
           
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Better to use `transform: translateY(-15px)`

Comment: @VilleKoo jerking/jumping will continue if you use the same div for hover.